# CORS Filter not working in spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, mongodb

Am struggling for last three days with the error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/demomongo/templateapp/login. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

```
Here is my code kindly help.



    Login.html
    <html ng-app="LoginApp">
    <body>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="LoginApp.js"> </script>
    <div ng-controller="loginController as login">
    Username <input type="text" ng-model="username" /><br/>
    Password <input type="text" ng-model="password" /><br/>
    <button ng-click="validate()">Validate</button>
    </div>
    <br/> <a href="Reg.html">Register Me/New user</a>

    </body>
    </html>

    LoginApp.js
    (function(){
    var app;
    app=angular.module('LoginApp',[]);
    app.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http){
     var dataObj = {
       "name" : "Java Honk",
       "password" : "NY"
         
       };
     $scope.validate = function() {
            dataObj.name=$scope.username;
            dataObj.password=$scope.password;

            
     //if($scope.username=="sam" && $scope.password=="pwd")
           // console.log("password match");
           // else
            //console.log("username/pwd not matching");
     $http.post('http://localhost:8080/demomongo/templateapp/login', dataObj)
                                .success(function(responseData) {
           $scope.responseData = responseData;
           console.log(responseData);
           }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
       });
        }
    });

    })();




CORSFilter:



    CORSFilter.java

    package com.demo.mongo.example.filter;

    import java.io.IOException;



    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

    public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
     private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CORSFilter.class);

     @Override
     protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      
      if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
       LOG.trace("Sending Header....");
       // CORS "pre-flight" request
       response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    //   response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
       response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
      }
      
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
     }

    }



Template Controller.java


    //templatecontroller.java
    package com.demo.mongo.example.controller;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

    import com.demo.mongo.example.model.UserDetails;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/templateapp")
    public class TemplateController {
     @CrossOrigin
     @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody String validateUser(@RequestBody UserDetails udata,UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
      /*UserDetails obj=new UserDetails();
      List<UserDetails> values=obj.UserDetails(udata.getName(),udata.getPassword());
      if(values.size()>0){
       return "welcome udata.getName";
      }
      else
      {
       return "please register using registration link";
      }*/
            if(udata.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("admin") &&  udata.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
            {
             return "welcome admin";
            }
            else
            {
             return "password mismatch/not an admin";
            }
     }
     @CrossOrigin
     @RequestMapping(value="/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody String addUser(@RequestBody UserDetails udata,UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
            
            return " new user details: name "+ udata.getName() + " Email Id " + udata.getEmailid() ;
     }
     
    }





UserDetails.Java



    package com.demo.mongo.example.model;
    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

    @Document
    public class UserDetails {
     @Id
     private String name;
     private String password;
     private String emailid;
     private int contact;

     public UserDetails(){}

     public UserDetails(String name,String password,String emailid,int contact){
      this.name=name;
      this.password=password;
      this.emailid=emailid;
      this.contact=contact;
     }

     public void setName(String name){
      this.name=name;
     }

     public void setPassword(String password){
      this.password=password;
     }
     
     public void setEmailid(String emailid){
      this.emailid=emailid;
     }
     public void setContact(int contact){
      this.contact=contact;
     }
     public String getPassword(){
      return this.password;
      
     }
     public String getName(){
      return this.name;
     }
     public int getContact(){
      return this.contact;
      
     }
     public String getEmailid(){
      return this.emailid;
      
     }
    }




**dispatcher-servlet.xml**



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


     <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.mongo.example" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        
     <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
     <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
      <property name="host" value="localhost" />
     </bean>
     
     <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and querying the documents in the database -->
     <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
      <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
      <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
     </bean>

     <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
     <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
        <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
       <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
       <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
     </bean>
    </beans>




web.xml



    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
      
      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

     <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

     

      <!-- Add this to your web.xml to enable "CORS" -->
     <filter>
       <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
       <filter-class>com.demo.mongo.example.filter.CORSFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
       
     <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>




pom.xml



    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.demo.mongo.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>demomongo</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>demomongo Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.1</version>
      </dependency>
      
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.2</version>
      </dependency>
      
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.1-1</version>
      </dependency>
      
      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
      </dependency>
      
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>demomongo</finalName>
      </build>
    </project>




please help to fix which i did wrong.
```

Comment: Avoid localhost, set a hostname

Answer (score 1):

You set header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in filter. If the header is not appearing make sure it is chained. Debug or log it.

Comment: protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: Pavel as you told i added setheader , still same error. What am still missing, plz help

Comment: Sorry for not answering.
But you did not tell do you really get this header in response. If you send request to your server, do receive the header in response?
And consider using same value in <url-pattern> both for dispatcher and filter.